# SSL - create client.crt and client.key for Python requests call

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

I'm new to Python and have been struggling with this for hours now, so I thought perhaps someone within the community would be able to help.

I am trying to connect to a 3rd party enterprise server which is not a global CA.

I have the following files

- my_csr.key (which I created myself) and is just the CSR that I sent to the 3rd party
- my_private.key (was created when making the my_csr.key above)
- their.pem (which 3rd party sent to me)
- my.p12

The steps I took are as follows:

1. I was instructed by the 3rd party to create a CSR as step 1.  Using openssl, I created my_csr.key (along with my_private.key) upon which I sent my_csr.key to the 3rd party
2. The 3rd party then took my CSR and sent me the file 'their.pem'
3. Using 'their.pem' and my_private.key, using openssl I created a .p12 which I can use successfully to make SSL verified HTTP requests in both C# and Java.  The openssl command to create the p12 was

   - **openssl pkcs12 -in their.pem -inkey my_private.key -export -out my.p12**

I've taken a look at python requests documentation:[python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) but I'm still not clear on the openssl commands I need to make in order to create a client.crt and the client.key using the cert argument or alternatively the verify argument.

What are the openssl commands I need to make given the files that I have in order to create a client.crt and client.key?

Below is the code I'm trying to run in python:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, cert=('their.pem', 'my_private.key'))
print(r.text)
```

I have also tried with my private key password ie:

```
r = requests.get(url, cert=('their.pem', 'my_private.key', 'private_key_password'))
```

But in both of these calls I get prompted to input 'Enter PEM pass phrase' upon which I enter my_private.key password, but both variations fail with the following error:
**requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)**

Comment: It might be that `my_csr.key` is the `client.key` and `their.pem` is the `client.crt` your are looking for. But maybe its not. Unfortunately when looking at this and then your previous questions it is not really clear what your final goal is  - while before it looked like you want to connect to a server where the server is using a self-signed server certificate now it looks like you want to connect to a server using a client certificate (i.e. mutual authentication) - which is a very different goal.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich ok, I think I'm understanding what you are saying now.  I thought it was a self signed certfiicate from my earlier post, but in fact to properly define what I'm doing, I believe it is mutual authentication.   I have just tried your suggestion to use 'their.pem' as the client.crt and 'my_csr.key' as the client.key and unfortunately that did not work.  I'll try to rephrase question

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ok, I'm pretty sure that you are correct and 'their.pem' is indeed the client.crt.  I found this link: https://blog.codeship.com/how-to-set-up-mutual-tls-authentication/ and here, they used the following command *openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in client/heiko.crt -inkey client/heiko.key -out client/heiko.p12* to create their p12 which is similar to mine (except I used their.pem as in.  I'll update my post with the open ssl command I used for p12.

Comment: I see - your `my_csr.key` is the CSR and not a key and just has the confusing `.key` extension (should be better called `my.csr`). Thus, try `my_private.key` instead as `client.key`. Also, your question includes no code to see what you are actually doing and no error messages to see why it fails.

Comment: Agree about my_csr.key is confusing.  Sorry, that was the 3rd party documentation who told me to do it that way.  Clearly I'm no ssl / cert expert ;)  I've updated question with code and I've tried your suggestion using my_private.key but when I do, I get asked to input 'Enter PEM pass phrase:'.  I enter my private.key password here, and then I get the error: **requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)**

Comment: *"...certificate verify failed'.."* - The problem at the moment is not your client certificate but that you cannot verify and thus trust the servers certificate. You don't have this in any of your files currently so you need to ask whoever has setup the server for the appropriate CA certificate to use. And use this `ca.pem` or whatever you call it then as the value for the `verify` parameter.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment.  I do have a .cer file from the 3rd party http server which I downloaded via browser when I loaded a webpage from their http server.  I tried to use the verify argument with this .cer file, but that did not work either.  I don't see a way using python requests to use client certs as well as this 3rd party .cer that I downloaded from their server.

Comment: You should not use the certificate for the server but the  root CA who issued the certificate.

Comment: Aha, this is why I raised it first as a python issue.  I don't need the root CA certificate in neither C# or Java to make this http request.  Only python is giving me trouble.  The 3rd party provider does not provide me with a CA certificate, and I can understand why especially if I'm able to make a successful http request in java / c# with a valid p12.  Thanks

Comment: If the server is using a certificate signed by a public CA maybe your trust store for Python is not properly setup. Try installing certifi as described [here](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/). But it might also be that a private CA is used and that the appropriate trust stores were setup on your system but not the trust store used by Python (all different trust stores). Too few things known about your environment.

Comment: I got it working using a p12 monkey patch and verify=False.  Not ideal but it will work for now.

Answer (score 0):

> A 3rd party enterprise server which is not a global CA.

```
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

It sounds as if you need to trust the root cert (since as you mentioned, this isn't a 'global' CA - which means it probably isn't in Windows or Linux's root store).

- Import the root PEM file into the root store for your OS.
- Use [the silly named `assert_hostname=False` option](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/194) to disable host verification. This is insecure and would allow anyone who could intercept your network connection to show a random certificate and recieve your data.

> VerifiedHTTPSConnection uses one of assert_fingerprint, assert_hostname and host in this order to verify connections. If assert_hostname is False, no verification is done.

See [the urllib3 docs](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/)

Comment: thanks for your reply.  When you say import the root PEM, are you referring to the file **their.pem** which the 3rd party sent me?  Thanks very much for clarifying, just want to make sure I'm trusting the correct file.  Thanks!

Comment: `their.pem` might have multiple certificates inside - open it up in a text editor and look (they'll be obvious). You might want to split these into seperate files. To read the file, run `openssl x509 -text -noout -in file.pem`. Typically a root level certificate is used to sign other certificates (this is required for public certs), but that may not be the case here.

Comment: Thanks mike.  I opened **their.pem** in a text editor and I can see only one instance of -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and the equivalent -----END CERTIFICATE----- so I presume that means one certificate.  I'm on MacOS, and I tried to add the .p12 to my keychain and completely trusted it and then re-ran my simple python requests GET call, but it made no difference and I still get the same error.  I then added **their.PEM** to keychain as well and completely truested, and still it made no difference unfortunately.

Comment: Hrm just to confirm, it should look like this (for MacOS): https://certsimple.com/images/blog/localhost-ssl-fix/trust-new-certificate.png

Comment: Hi, exactly, i double clicked into the cert, and I made sure it was "always trust".  Just to confirm, I also confirmed the cert by opening a web page on the 3rd party server in Safari (if cert isn't trusted, Safari won't return the test web page)